# How do I combine similar dates based on a particular value?

Tags: python

```
Trade Date  Options Class   Underlying  Product Type    Volume
0   2022-01-03  A   A   S   14
1   2022-01-03  A   A   S   3
2   2022-01-03  A   A   S   42
3   2022-01-03  A   A   S   10
4   2022-01-03  AA  AA  S   1924


print(df.groupby('Trade Date','Underlying').sum())
```

How do combine all the similar dates together based on a particular underlying?

For example in the above example i will get a single line of 2022-01-03 for A with the sum of its volume

I tried using:

```
print(df.groupby('Trade Date','Underlying').sum())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem is not understandable. What do you mean by "similar"? (i.e., what is the **rule that tells you** whether two dates are "similar" or not?) What do you mean by "particular underlying"? For the input that you show, **exactly** what should the output be, and **why**?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Trade Date', 'Underlying'])['Volume'].sum()
```

output:

```
>     Trade Date  Underlying
>     2022-01-03  A               69
>                 AA            1924
>     Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you can in fact use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) but you need to put the groups/columns inside square brackets instead of parenthesis. Also, you need to select only columns which should be valid for the sum (`Volume` in your case), otherwise you'll get a warning :

> FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in
> DataFrameGroupBy.sum is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only
> will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only
> columns which should be valid for the function.

Try this :

```
out= df.groupby(["Trade Date", "Underlying"], as_index=False)["Volume"].sum()
```

Or this :

```
out= df.groupby(["Trade Date", "Underlying"], as_index=False).sum(numeric_only=True)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   Trade Date Underlying  Volume
0  2022-01-03          A      69
1  2022-01-03         AA    1924
```